# Paste variable values to image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I have this jQuery/Javascript-Code

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #baseurl{visibility: hidden!important;}
    #options{visibility: hidden!important;}
    #key{visibility: hidden!important;}
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cityoutput").val($.trim($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("City")').siblings(".ms-formbody").text()));
    $("#stateoutput").val($.trim($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("State")').siblings(".ms-formbody").text()));

    var cityoutput = $("#cityoutput").val();
    var stateoutput = $("#stateoutput").val();
    var baseurl = $("#baseurl").val();
    var options = $("#options").val();
    var key = $("#key").val();

    $("#mapbutton").click(function() {

    alert(baseurl + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + options + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + key);

    });

    });

    </script>

    <input disabled="disabled" id="cityoutput" maxlength="255" min="1"/>&#160;
    <input disabled="disabled" id="stateoutput" maxlength="255" min="1"/>
    <input id="mapbutton" type="button" value="Show url"/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="baseurl" value="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="options" value="&amp;zoom=16&amp;size=600x300&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;format=png&amp;markers=color:red%7C"/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="key" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

On the line with the alert I need to change something. This is building a URL for me and I need the created URL for a image src="".

How is it possible to paste the URL as the  but only if I click on my button?

I think it's quite simple but I don't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get you correctly but based on your code i think this is what you want.

Hope this helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #baseurl{visibility: hidden!important;}
    #options{visibility: hidden!important;}
    #key{visibility: hidden!important;}
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cityoutput").val($.trim($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("City")').siblings(".ms-formbody").text()));
    $("#stateoutput").val($.trim($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("State")').siblings(".ms-formbody").text()));

    var cityoutput = $("#cityoutput").val();
    var stateoutput = $("#stateoutput").val();
    var baseurl = $("#baseurl").val();
    var options = $("#options").val();
    var key = $("#key").val();

    $("#mapbutton").click(function() {

    alert(baseurl + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + options + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + key);

    var src_url=baseurl + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + options + cityoutput + "," + stateoutput + key;
  
    //pasting the url in img src
    $("#url_target").attr('src',src_url);

    });

    });

    </script>

    <input disabled="disabled" id="cityoutput" maxlength="255" min="1"/>&#160;
    <input disabled="disabled" id="stateoutput" maxlength="255" min="1"/>
    <input id="mapbutton" type="button" value="Show url"/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="baseurl" value="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="options" value="&amp;zoom=16&amp;size=600x300&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;format=png&amp;markers=color:red%7C"/>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="key" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    
    <img id='url_target'/>
```